# Prevent simultaneous DB Transactions on play2.1 application

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.0, ebean

I came across a serious issue with our payment workflow today.
Once a payment is completed, two things happen:

- the user gets redirected to a success-page on our server, the redirect also appends the payment id
- the payment provider sends a payment notification including the payment id to our server

When the user gets redirected to the success-page we check whether a payment with the payment id exists. If this is not the case we create a `pending` payment that we can show to him.

When the payment provider sends a payment notification we check whether there exists a `pending` payment with the payment id and set it to `active`, if no payment exists we just create an `active` one.

Here's the problem: Both events can (and did!) happen simultaniously such that both routines did not find an existing payment and so two payments got created. One `pending` and one `active`.

Is there a good way to circumvent this behaviour by possibly using locks or something?
I'm using the default Ebean ORM on a java based play 2.1.0 with a MySQL db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Play thing at all. My advice is to not use locks. If you do then you will limit the scalability of your application.

You need to cope with this race condition. Race conditions will always occur and there's nothing you can do to prevent them. So, embrace them.

In the instance you describe its sounds like the pending state should be overridden by the active state if both exist in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
I realise that this is not play's fault. I just wanted to mention the environment I'm working in since I was hoping that there might be some specific configurations/tools that could prevent such race conditions.
So I guess I'll restructure my code to react if an sql exception is thrown to do the right thing in the corresponding routine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answers your question or not, but [here is a link](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introtrans_txrunnable.html) to the Ebean transactions page.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into the play code to see how transactions are handled and how I can deal with these from my controller.